# Other the UIStackView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistackview

I made 16 button as pictures as you can see in the phone below, when I looked at my iPhone when I'm holding it portrait it shows well but when I moved the iPhone to be landscape, it looked messed up! After I finished the first row and it was well, I copied and pasted it to be the second row, and copied the first and the second row and pasted it to be row number 3 and 4.

I used UIStackView with it but the UIStackView doesn't work with iPhone 4 and I have an iPhone 4.

The question is, does anyone recommend what to use?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You could try using a UICollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UICollectionView`. There are a lot of samples of using it. Here is one provided by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html.